# Selecting rows absent from one table against two other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have three tables I am trying to build a query against in Eloquent to get only the rows from two tables that are absent from a third table.

One is the table `histories` which references the other two tables `schedules` and `templates`. If there is a template schedule history, I don't want to get that schedule.

Normally I would expect this could be done using a `LEFT JOIN` on the third table where the id `IS NULL` but this doesn't work in this instance. Every query I have tried thus far always returns the null columns along with the row I don't want.

Here is a fiddle with the relevant schema and an example query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28aad/5

How can I structure my query to get the results desired?

Comment: if you want schedules that don't have a related history, and you're trying to get that with an anti-join pattern, it looks like the predicate that's checking whether there's a match (`histories.id IS NULL`) should be in the `WHERE` clause, rather than the `ON` clause of the outer join operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    schedules . *,
    schedules.id as 'schedule_id',
    histories . *,
    histories.id as 'history_id'
from
    schedules
left join
    histories ON schedules.id = histories.schedule_id
        and schedules.template_id = histories.template_id
where
    histories.id IS NOT NULL
;
```

This lists schedules IDs 1 & 2

```
select 
    schedules . *,
    schedules.id as 'schedule_id',
    histories . *,
    histories.id as 'history_id'
from
    schedules
left join
    histories ON schedules.id = histories.schedule_id
        and schedules.template_id = histories.template_id
where
    histories.id IS NULL
;
```

This lists schedule ID 3 , but this does not match other conditions such as

- schedules.schedulable_id = 16

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28aad/21

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:  However your query is not returning any results because each schedule/template has a history record.

```
select 
    histories . *,
    histories.id as 'history_id',
    schedules . *,
    schedules.id as 'schedule_id'
from
    schedules
left join
    histories ON schedules.id = histories.schedule_id
        and schedules.template_id = histories.template_id
where
    schedules.schedulable_id = 16
    and schedules.schedulable_type = 'Item'
    and histories.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Schedule ID 3 is not in the histories table, so shouldn't it come up in the results?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to get rows for `schedules` table which are not in `histories` table, your eloquent query would be such:

```
//Fetches list of schedule IDs from Histories table
$schedule_ids = Histories::distinct()->lists('schedule_id')
//Get list of all schedules which are not present in Histories table
$queryresult = Schedules::WhereNotIn('id', $schedule_ids)->get();`
```